# Expectation of matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, hessian-matrix

Denote a matrix A such that A$\in \mathbb{C}^{M\times N}$, and each element of this matrix is modeled to follow a complex Gaussian distribution with zero mean and unit variance, and each element is independent to each other.

I think that $E\left\{A^HA\right\}=M\cdot I$, where $I$ is an identity matrix, but some people think that $ E\left\{A^HA\right\}=I$.

I am confused which one is right. Could you please help me?